# Ionic V4 : How to declare common piece of HTML code to be recalled all over pages?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have created and published an Ionic V4 application that works fine.

I want now to clean it and reduce its coding size. 
In this app I have a piece of HTML (just text) that is repeated all over pages. 
Currently I have repeated it in each page and this is not nice.

To avoid this repetition, I have created a service named htlmCommon. 
In it I declare variables containing the HTML code. (example  `msg1 :string =”<h1> Hello from HtmlCommon </h1>”;`*)

I refer this service in my page and I call this variable via `<div [innerHTML]='this.HtmlCommon.msg1'></div>`

It works fine but the variable cannot have ionic tag (like `<ion-row>, <ion-col>` etc..). 
It gets screw up

How can I go around this? 
Or maybe my way to proceed is not correct !

The reason I have created a new service is because the default one “gobal-info.service.ts” is already loaded with all my common methods.

Thanks

Comment: Use ng-templete for faster work instead of innerHtml.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and in its html file add the html you want to use in all common pages. Say you created your component as commonHTMLComponent, then:

commonHTML.component.html

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>col 1</ion-col>
        <ion-col>col 2</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

commonHTML.component.ts

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-common-html'
})
```

Now you can use this selector anywhere in your application to embed the common html like:

```
<app-common-html></app-common-html>
```

Comment: Yes, I will do it for my biggest common HTML code. But, if I understand it, one component has to be crated for each piece of common HTML code. 
I was searching a way to collect all those commons parts into one file. Like what is done for all common methods declared in one service file.
I could see a mixture, your solution for big pieces of HTML code and my approach for standard HTML small pieces (containing only referenced HTML tags).

Comment: Well 1 approach is to add *ngIf in your html and pass the parameter to selector to enable particular html. e.g <ion-grid *ngIf="htmlCode1">stuff here..</ion-grid> and selector would be <app-common-html [htmlCode1]="true"></app-common-html>

Comment: Hi, about my first goal : I want now to clean it and reduce its coding size… 
To clean it : proposal mentioned by answer seems good . I have applied them.
To squeeze the code : Quite simple when we know it. ( I have discovered it yesterday) 
IONIC V4 has a file management bug . (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3954 ) 
The ../src/www  folder is not cleaned before each rebuild, and the apk gets bigger and bigger. 
 Thus before every publication, delete the ../src/www file.